# Create Query either using Select by Attributes or Python

Tags: python, query, excel, idle, spyder

I am working on something for my job, where I have a list of water/sewer service customers. Some customers have one service or the other, while others have both which is stored as two separate entries. I need to figure out a way to create a table that separates the sewer customers, water customers, and combines those that have both. Does anyone have any ideas or scripts that would give me this outcome?

This is what I have:
[image]

This is what I need:
[image]

Comment: Please specify which programme you are using and whether you would be comfortable with SQL language solutions.

Comment: This is using ArcMap. I have never used SQL, but I can give it a try. Python language is the only one I have ever used, but I can probably work it out if you had an idea for a SQL solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Address is unique to a customer (may be user customer ID instead) and that there can only ever be water or sewer as service types then a simple aggregate by customer counting on type will give you a 1 or a 2 for each customer address. You don't state in your question which GIS system you are using so assuming you are using ArcMap then this is the summary tool. Join back the original service type and then update the rows which are 2 to "both".

Comment: Yeah, sorry it is ArcMap. Thanks for the response, I will go and try that now.